# Netbeans Web application .html .jsp

Tags: netbeans, web, project

When I open a new project in netbeans the IDE always creates index.html instead of index.jsp.

I am using the classfish server.

How do I get it to create the .jsp file?

This how I begin.
Choose File > New Project (Ctrl-Shift-N) from the main menu. Under Categories, select Java Web. Under Projects, select Web Application then click Next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has changed (in 7.3.1 I believe). If you create Java Web project with JavaEE version set to "Java EE 7 Web", then it creates HTML page. If you choose e.g. "Java EE 6 Web", then it creates JSP page. I believe there is no way to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I got your question, however I'm writing in different context:
Whenever you run your project in NetBeans - If you want to run any 'specified UI file' by default instead of 'index.html file', then we need to perform few quick steps:

1. Select and Right click on project from Projects explorer from left bar.
2. Select properties.
3. Under categories, click on "Run".
4. Change context path towards the specific file and click "OK" to save.

For example: I've a project named "DemoJSP1" and the "add.jsp" file I've created and want to run during project running is under "Web Pages" folder.

So the context path by default will be like this: '/DemoJSP1', here I've to change context path to '/DemoJSP1/Web pages/add.jsp' and save
the settings by clicking OK.

Now when we run the project, it would load the 'add.jsp' file first by default.