# NetBeans - new Java Web Project - html vs jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, netbeans

I found this question:
[Netbeans Web application .html .jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455250/netbeans-web-application-html-jsp)

I have the same issue. Is there a way to change it somewhere somehow?
Or if I create a new .jsp file in the same project, how do I make runnable(when I click on Run on Server to load the .jsp file and to threat that one as default instead of the .html)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using Glassfish and if you do, what version?

Comment: @fvu Yes, I am using GlassFish 4 with NetBeans 8.0 and JDK/JRE 8 on Win8 64bit :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netbeans Web application .html .jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455250/netbeans-web-application-html-jsp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but I think that you're referring to the welcome files mechanism. What file this mechanism prefers depends on the version of Glassfish/JavaEE you're using as in more recent versions jsp is kind of deprecated.  As you mention jsp I also assume that you're not using faces.

The easiest way to control what file or files gets offered as default file you have to edit web.xml, the standard deployment file (which became optional in EE6 but if it's there it will still be consulted:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

As stated in [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html#bnaer):

> If a web container receives a valid partial request, the web container examines the welcome file list and appends to the partial request each welcome file in the order specified and checks whether a static resource or servlet in the WAR is mapped to that request URL. The web container then sends the request to the first resource that matches in the WAR.

With Netbeans you can also edit this list via the web.xml file, under the "Pages" tab.

Comment: I checked and the web.xml is also not generated. I had create it on my own and then edit and add index.jsp as one of the welcome files. But it is a little bit annoying to do that every time.

Comment: @Tanata05 just rightclick on the project node in the projects view, select new, standard deployyment descriptor and the web.xml file will be created with basic settings.  Then, find it in WEB-INF, doubleclick it and edit with the provided wizards or directly by editing the xml file.  Before it was generated automatically when you generated a project, but since JEE6 it's optional and that's why it's not generated by default.

Comment: @Tanata05 also, you could also just delete the autogenerated index.html file, as far as I know it should pick up the index.jsp file as the default welcome file unless they changed that behavior in GF4.

Comment: I deleted index.html and then added index.jsp and when I ran the project directly like that it came up with 404 error. And then I created the web.xml as you told me and added the index.jsp in the welcome file list and it was working after. Only after I entered the index.jsp in the welcome file list in the web.xml, the Run was successful.

Answer (score 0):

delete the `index.html`, create a new page called `index.jsp` and inside `faces-config.xml` change all occurrences of `index.html` to `index.jsp`

Comment: @j.com Thanks. Do you know where I can find faces-config.xml ? Sorry for noobish questions, but I am new to Java Web Programming

Comment: in the WEB-INF folder

Comment: The file was not there. I had to manually create the file and add it to the project? Is there any way to be generated automatically ?

Comment: @Tanata05 unless you selected `Javaserver Faces` in the `Frameworks` list that file won't be there, and it won't do much in in non-JSF projects either.